# exception not caught in node.js add-on

Tags: c++, node.js, exception, armadillo

I am currently writing a wrapper class based on ObjectWrap for the armadillo linear algebra library. I have noticed that when an exception is emitted from armadillo, it is not caught in the add-on code even when i try to handle the exception:

```
if(args[0].isString()){
    try{
        std::string s(*v8::String::AsciiValue(args[0]->ToString()));
        MatrixWrap* matrix = new MatrixWrap(s);
        matrix->Wrap(args.This());
    }catch(exception& e){
        cout << "caught exception" << endl;  // this code is never called.
    }
}
```

The corresponding corresponding constructor is given below (_matrix is an instance of arma::mat and throws an exception if the string is not correctly formatted):

```
MatrixWrap::MatrixWrap(string s):_matrix(s){

}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
> var arma = require('./build/Release/armadillo');
> var matrix = new arma.Matrix('1 0; 0 1');
> matrix.print();
1.0000        0
    0   1.0000

> var B = new arma.Matrix('1 0; 0');

error: Mat::init(): inconsistent number of columns in given string
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

It's as if the exception is not handled despite the catch clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *catch(exception& e)*, try using *catch(...)* which should catch all exceptions.

Depending on the error, Armadillo throws std::logic_error, std::bad_alloc, or std::runtime_error

Comment: I tried that initially but somehow it seems that the exception is simply not caught and propagates until the application is terminated

Comment: Strange. Try refactoring your code to minimize the use of pointers (eg. don't do manual memory management; reduce or remove calls to _new_, _delete_, _malloc()_, _free()_, etc). Pointers are low-level and very error prone. They can lead to the errors surfacing far away from where the actual problem is.

Comment: I am really not doing much with pointers here. Exception handling should be predictable. I think this has more to do with having an exception propagate from one shared library (armadillo) to another (node add-on). Somehow it s not propagated to the the add-on.

Comment: I'm tempted to say this might be a compiler issue. Going by the output you've given above, it looks like Clang is being used. Clang is still a work-in-progress, in contrast to the mature gcc compiler.

Comment: OK followed your advice and used centos/g++. When building the add-on, g++ complains about exception not being enabled. Realized that Armadillo is build with exception handling enabled and for some reason it's not the case by default when building node add-ons. I modified the the build script accordingly and now everything works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modified build script to enable exception handling:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            'target_name': 'armadillo',
            'sources':[ "src/addon.cpp", "src/MatrixWrap.cpp"],
            'link_settings': {
                'libraries': ['-larmadillo']
            },
            'cflags': ['-fexceptions'],
            'cflags_cc': ['-fexceptions']
        }
   ]
}
```